# set default browser (all users) from CL?

Tags: macos, terminal, applications, web-browser

Is it possible to set the default web browser for the computer (i.e. for all users) from the command line?

If I understand correctly, individual users' browser preferences are stored in ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist; is there a way of directly setting the default browser system-wide, or do I need to find a way of altering this .plist for everyone?

(Thanks in advance, any help would be appreciated!)